# How can I convert an XML Object into a Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have a project I need to do that requires the use of xml and javascript, however I'm not experienced in either.

Basicly its for a company that posts jobs in an rss feed using xml, and what they need is to have a page that allows a user to type in a search query, click a search button and have a list of available jobs returned back to them with only the title and the link, and upon clicking the link they will be directed to the full rss xml item. which they can then read.

Now as far as my logic goes, I don't know how to use jquery and quite honestly I don't think its necesary, I think that all this project needs is a bit of ajax however firstly one would need to create an xml object, convert it to a javascript object and only then manipulate it. etc...

If anyone has any insight I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Any reason why you think that all processing should be done on client side via AJAX/JavaScript?

Comment: Do you use .Net for your server side ?